# SQLServerCallableStatement not returing the result set

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying out a simple test and so I have a simple stored procedure. It selects rows from a table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_SQL_Connect] 
as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 
select * from [dbo].[Test_Sqlconnector]
END
```

When I run exec [dbo].[Test_SQL_Connect] ..the output is

TagName TagValue    Timestamp   TagStatus

tag1    value1  2017-01-31 19:09:43.7570000 1

In Java, I have the following code(connection has been created earlier)

```
SQLServerCallableStatement cStatement = 
                (SQLServerCallableStatement)connection.prepareCall("{call dbo.Test_SQL_Connect}");
cStatement.execute();
```

After execution the value of cStatement.getUpdateCount() = -1 .

Would anyone know why the updatecount is -1 even though 1 record is returned?

Comment: Did you read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount())?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result of [Statement.getUpdateCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount())

> Retrieves the current result as an update count; **if the result is a
>   ResultSet object** or there are no more results, **-1 is returned**.
>   This method should be called only once per result.

Also have a look at the javadoc of [PreparedStatement.execute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()).